# svn connector is still empty after install subversive and subversive connector

Tags: svn, connector, subversive, eclipse-neon

First, I download PDT, which is latest version Neon 4.6.1. https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

Second, I download subversive which is latest version 4.0.2 for neon.https://eclipse.org/subversive/latest-releases.php.

Third, install subversive by steps and restart eclipse.

Everything is ok.

Then open Windows->Preferences->Team->SVN,will find SVN Connector combobox is empty.I know i need to install SVN Connector now.

Forth, download and install subversive connector with the latest version 6.0.0. http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/builds/?__hstc=2015854.c7d284170a44fe73e529496bb0f74d2d.1479204107043.1479204107043.1479266265875.2&__hssc=2015854.1.1479266265875&__hsfp=2552076761

I have restarted my eclipse, but unfortunately svn connector is still empty. Why? What's the trick or possible reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't resolve this issue. The offline installation of subversive and SVN Connector is a hard work. I have to turn to online installation, then copy the version to my offline PC as a workaround method.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not that late, it all depends on how it is your instalation, I had a similar problem and using the instaler.exe of eclipse you can access to an advance version of it, there you can manage your bundle pool anaalyze it and clean it, then reinstall connectors, it solved for me, but I dont know if you are even using windows to this solution, but the oomph installer should fix this problem